# Find slow/ineffecient method calls in dotnet

Tags: .net

I'm faced with a big old stack of method calls in some legacy code, one or some of which is creating a bottleneck and really slowing things down. Is there any quick way I can get a report on which method calls are taking the time, short of running in debug, stepping through and seeing where the cursor pauses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Eqatec](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler)

Comment: Interesting - I haven't come across that one before. I'll give it a try and see how it compares with dotTrace...

Comment: Okay, I'm already somewhat put off by the fact that they claim it's free on the download page - but then you read on and find out that it's a free 30 day evaluation.

Comment: @Jon, their Free license is for non-commercial projects. For commercial projects the user should purchase a Personal license.

Comment: @Nick D: Ah, I misread it as saying the personal was for even non-commercial use after 30 days.

Comment: Marketing weasels up to their tricks again! At least it's free for non-commercial projects.

Comment: Check the EQATEC site tomorrow: the license terms are just about to change radically, and the R&D camp has overcome the marketing weasels :-)

Comment: @Joe: I don't think it was really a marketing problem in this case - I only expected it to be free for non-commercial use. I then just failed to read the licence terms properly :(

Answer (score 11):

Use a profiler. I personally use [JetBrains dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) but that's mainly because I was given a free licence as an MVP. There are other tools available too, such as [RedGate's ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm). I haven't used the ANTS one myself.

There's a [free profiler from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A362781C-3870-43BE-8926-862B40AA0CD0&displaylang=en) which targets .NET 2.0; I expect it would work with .NET 3.0 and 3.5 as well, but quite possibly not .NET 4 as that has a new CLR. My own experience with this is that it's somewhat limited, but can still be useful.

Comment: +1. I've tried ANTS before (trial version) and got on well with it. I don't know how it compares to dotTrace, but may be worth trialling both

Answer (score 3):

[SlimTune](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/) is another free and open source profiler.